# Which is the best PHP MVC framework?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and this forum, I just would like to know which is the best PHP MVC framework regarding to performance and scalable at the present? I wonder if Yii is the best one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no **best** MVC framework. Use the one that you are comfortable with. Here are some list of MVC frameworks that you would want to lookat

1. Yii
2. CodeIgniter
3. CakePHP
4. Symfony2
5. Zend Framework
6. Laravel

or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPHP_frameworks) is the entire list of PHP frameworks

Comment: what about laravel? I hear a lot about it

Comment: oh yes, how can i forget laravel! silly of me. Thanks @meda.